# If $\phi$ is $\Delta^{0}_{1}$ in the language of arithmetic, does Heyting Arithmetic prove $\forall x [\phi (x) \vee \neg \phi (x)]$?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, constructive-mathematics

PA is conservative over HA for $\Pi^{0}_{2}$ sentences. If $\phi$ is $\Delta^{0}_{1}$, then $\forall x [\phi (x) \vee \neg \phi (x)]$ is equivalent to a $\Pi^{0}_{2}$ sentence. Since PA trivially proves that sentence in the language of arithmetic, oughtn't HA to too? What am I missing?

(The usual counterexample offered for $\Pi^{0}_{3}$ sentneces is an instance of the same applied to $\phi$ of $\Sigma^{0}_{2}$ complexity, which made me think...)

Comment: Are you sure about "$\mathsf {PA}$ is conservative over $\mathsf {HA}$ for $\Pi^{0}_{2}$ sentences" ? See Anne Troelstra & Dirk van Dalen, *Constructivism in mathematics An Introduction* (1988), page 128 : "*Proposition* (ii) For $A$ not containing $\lor$ or $\exists$ : $\mathsf {HA} \vdash A$ iff $\mathsf {PA} \vdash A$. [...] The proposition does not cover theorems of the 
form $\forall x \exists y A(x, y)$, $A$ quantifier-free (i.e. theorem in $\Pi^{0}_{2}$-form)."

Comment: That's interesting and confusing in equal measure. I'm currently trying to get my head round G\o"del's D-interpretation. A consequence of that, as expounded in Feferman/Avigad (1998) can be found on p. 18 (found on Feferman's website): {\bf Corollary 3.2.5: PA and HA + Markov's principle are conservative over HA for $\Pi^{0}_{2}$ sentences. The proof uses the fact that the functional interpretation proves the $\Pi_{2}$ sentences of PA and can be formalized in HA. Be interested to know why the apparant inconsistency! Thanks for your response

Comment: But what is $\phi(x)$ ? It is of the form $\exists y \psi(x,y)$ ? If so, are we sure that $∀x[ϕ(x) \lor \lnot ϕ(x)]$ i.e.  $∀x[\exists y \psi(x,y) \lor \lnot \exists y \psi(x,y)]$ i.e. $∀x[\exists y \psi(x,y) \lor \forall y \lnot \psi(x,y)]$ is of the "right form" ?

Comment: good question. It might very well turn on intuitionistic logic not proving the required equivalence. I was thinking that since $\phi (x) \leftrightarrow \exists (y) \psi (x,y)$ and $\neg \phi(x) \leftrightarrow \neg \forall z \theta (x,z) \leftrightarrow \exists z \neg \theta (x,z)$ in PA, we can write $\forall x [\phi (x) \vee \neg \phi (x)]$ as $\forall x \exists y,z[ \psi (x,y) \vee \neg \theta (x,z)]$ which is provable in PA (and ex hypothesi in HA). Does HA get us back to the original formula though? The directions of equivalence we need seem intuitionisitcally valid....

Comment: @chris scambler: it is acceptable to delete comments if you no longer think they are useful. I wrote up an argument in an answer that I think answers your question. Could you let me know if it does? One thing that does seem to be a sensitive issue is to represent the "$\Delta^0_1$" nature of the formula correctly, because of course there will be limited ability to handle negations in HA. But if we make the correct assumption, (*) in my answer, then it seems there is no issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\phi(x,y)$ and $\psi(x,y)$ are quantifier free formulas of PA such that 
$$
\text{HA} \vdash (\forall x)[(\exists z)\phi(x,z) \leftrightarrow \lnot (\exists y)\psi(x,y)] \qquad (*)
$$
then in HA we can prove the following sequence of formulas are all pairwise equivalent:
$$
\begin{split}
&(\forall x)[(\exists y)\psi(x,y) \lor \lnot (\exists y)\psi(x,y)] \\
&(\forall x)[(\exists y)\psi(x,y) \lor (\exists z)\phi(x,z)] \qquad\qquad(\dagger)\\
&(\forall x)(\exists y)(\exists z)[\psi(x,y)\lor \phi(x,z)]
\end{split}
$$
The equivalence of the first two is by assumption. The equivalence of the second and third can be checked (among other ways) by verifying that the equivalence holds in every Kripke model.

Using the standard number theoretic method to combine existential number quantifiers, which can be formalized in HA, the last formula in the list above is equivalent over HA (and thus also over PA) to a formula of the form
$$
(\forall x)(\exists x)\theta(x,w)
$$
where $\theta$ is $\Delta^0_0$, that is, $\theta$ has only bounded quantifiers.

Therefore, by the result that PA is conservative over HA for $\Pi^0_2$ sentences of PA, we have that
$$
\text{PA} \vdash (\forall x)[(\exists y)\psi(x,y) \lor \lnot (\exists z)\psi(x,z)] 
$$
if and only if 
$$
\text{HA} \vdash (\forall x)[(\exists y)\psi(x,y) \lor \lnot (\exists z)\psi(x,z)] 
$$
as long as (*) above holds for $\psi$.

The limitation in this result is that we assumed (*) above at the beginning, and in particular that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are quantifier-free (we could take them to be $\Delta^0_0$ as well).

Comment: Thus, it is right to say that your (*) does not "violate" the principle that $\forall x[\varphi(x) \lor \lnot \varphi(x)]$ is **not** (in general) intuitionistically acceptable ?

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: the assumption is that (*) is provable in HA; the result doesn't apply otherwise. For example, if $\phi$ in the language of PA has no quantifiers at all then the formula in your comment is always provable in HA.

Comment: @chris scambler: there is an issue whether the subformula being quantified over is a bounded quantifier formula (which is what Avigad and Feferman call $\Delta^0_0$) or whether it's genuinely quantifier free.

Comment: @Carl Mummert: Thanks very much for your detailed response !! I take it (*) does not in general follow from $\phi$ being $\Delta^{0}_{1}$ in HA due to the failure of classical quantifier equivalences (specifically between a universal and a doubly negated existential)? Also, are you confirming PA's conservativity over HA? Was that a recent(ish) discovery, post 88? Thanks again, C

Comment: @carl: Excellent thanks for the second comment... so the result goes through only with $\Delta^{0}_{1}$ formulas which quantify over formulas with no qfiers at all?

Comment: @chris scambler: there's no such thing as a "$\Delta^0_1$ formula"; the arithmetical hierarchy for formulas does not include any $\Delta$ class except $\Delta^0_0$. What (`*`) says is that a certain *definable set* is $\Delta^0_1$ - namely, $\{z : (\exists x)\phi(x,z)\}$. But it's true there are various ways that the definition of a "$\Delta^0_1$ definable set" could be phrased, that would be classically equivalent through the manipulation of negations, which may not be equivalent in constructive logic. In (*) I could have let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be $\Delta^0_0$, and the argument goes through.

Comment: And none of this is new, since it is all just an application of Goedel's method.

Comment: Sorry about this, but now I'm a little confused: what is the issue concerning the subformula being qfier free/ containing bounded qfiers? Thanks for clearing up the formula/set thing, This stuff is all very new for me, as you can prob. tell.

Comment: @chrisscambler - I think that if the $\phi$ in your formula is *quantifier free* (or with *bounded quantifiers*) the formula is *decidable* (e.g. $x=5 \lor \lnot x=5$ is "checkable" in a finite number of steps, so it is provable in $\mathsf {HA}$). But there are *counterexample* to the "general case"; see AS Troelstra & D.van Dalen; *Constructivism in mathematics* (1988), page 13: whit $\forall n (A(n) \lor \lnot A(n))$, with $A(n)$ decidable but such that $\forall n A(n)$ is unknown, "At the time of [the book] we might take 'Fermat's last theorem' as an example of such $A$".

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: I don't think that example, in particular, is a counterexample to what we are trying to prove. Could you explain? I mean, PA proves that each $n$ either is or is not a counterexample to Con(PA), but PA doesn't prove Con(PA). So the issue does not seem related to constructive logic.

Comment: @CarlMummert - I'm referring to *Weak counterexamples* in [Intuitionism in the Philosophy of Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/); apart from the reference to the "supersed" Fermat's last theorem, I think that an Intuitionist can cook up a new example of "$A(n)$ decidable property for which $∀nA(n)$ is not known to be true or false." I'm trying to understand why in this case the above result does not apply : because the $\phi(x)$ is of the form $\forall y A(n,y)$ and not $\exists y \psi(x,y)$ ?

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: which result in particular are you claiming does not apply? My answer above does not claim that some general formula of the form $(\forall n)A(n)$ is provable.  In fact, for weak counterexample, we usually do *not* have a proof of $(\forall n)A(n)$.

Comment: @CarlMummert - this is exactly what I'm not still grasping. What is the "stricter" condition in your formula that escape from the intuitionistic critique ?

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: it is true that some constructive systems do not prove every instance of the scheme $(\forall n)(A(n) \lor \lnot A(n))$. Usually, a predicate $A$ for which that is provable is called "decidable" (using the same word as computability but with a different meaning).  The point of the question is that, in HA, certain instances of that scheme are provable. For example, HA proves that each $\Delta^0_0$ set of natural numbers is decidable.

Comment: @CarlMummert - Ok thanks!